# getValue() does not return the data from the source file, Google App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, getvalue

I have a simple script below to get the value of the last row in column P but when I execute it does not return any value at all. The source cell has this in it 'E2&"gmail.com"', where it should return an email address:

Below is the script I created

```
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("L0 Scores");

  var LastRow = ss.getLastRow();

  var LastCol = ss.getLastColumn();

  var Range = ss.getRange(1, 1, LastRow, LastCol);

  var RangeValues = Range.getValues();

  var Admin

  for (i=LastRow; i<=LastRow; i++){

Admin = ss.getRange('P'+i).getValue();

Logger.log(Admin);
  }

}
```

and this is what happens when I check the log

[image: Execution Log]

Thanks in advance

Comment: I did and the log displays this:  1:34:43 AM Notice Execution started
1:34:44 AM Info 
1:34:45 AM Notice Execution completed

Comment: You should check logs at view>logs. Not view>executions or view>stackdriver logs... or press ctrl+enter

Comment: im using the new editor, in the old editor this what i get: [20-02-25 09:38:13:115 PST]

Comment: Log last row and see whether P{lastRow} contains a value. (Side note: The Loop is entirely unnecessary though)

Comment: I was able to adjust the data source and it is now working fine, however, I was hoping to use query and when I do it that it is when the problem starts, will getlastrow also consider cells that are not populated?

Comment: Thanks for the help but its working now, I just deleted all the rows that has no value.

Comment: I'll try the syntax seen in the link you provided. Will update you soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function valueInLastRowColP() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName("L0 Scores");
  var rg=sh.getRange(sh.getLastRow(),16);
  return rg.getValue();
}
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: I was doing an MailApp function and was getting a No recipient error. Tried to check the log an it was not returning the value in the cell. I'll try both ways the one provided by TheMaster and urself. Thanks in advance